Events from Firebase Analytics not showing up in Big Query after a specific date
I have linked Firebase with BigQuery, and I was receiving the 'app_open' event from Firebase in BigQuery until a certain date. After that, it stopped. How can I fix this issue?
I wanted to know how many users open the app and how many times they do so. For this, I need the 'app_open' event.

app_open is not automatically collected event by Firebase SDK. So it means that the event has been implemented by your mobile app developers. If you don't see the event in BigQuery export after certain date, it means that you stopped tracking the event. I would recommend to discuss this with your developers and fix the tracking in the mobile app.
